# Dynamic fields using PHP Form Builder Class

Tags: php

I am using a PHP form Builder class v3.1
http://code.google.com/p/php-form-builder-class/

I am trying to create a dynamic form

```
$options = array("Amount", "Reset Password");
$form->addElement(new Element\Radio("Command Type to Employee : ", "type", $options));

$form->addElement(new Element\TextBox("Amount :", "amount"));
$form->addElement(new Element\TextBox("New Password:", "password"));
```

when I select the "Amount" radio button the "amount" text field should show and

when I select the "Reset password" radio button the "password" text field should show.

Can anyone kindly help me regarding with it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have jquery setup for your project, you can use the following in a view script after you render your form. This is untested, but it should work.

```
<?php 
    // ... setup $form
    $form->render();
?>
<script>
$(function(){
    var amountElements = $('input[name=amount]').prev('label').andSelf();
    var passwordElements = $('input[name=password]').prev('label').andSelf();
    $('input[name=type]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Reset Password') {
            amountElements.hide();
            passwordElements.show();
        } else {
            amountElements.show();
            passwordElements.hide();
        }
    });

    // trigger the event for the selected radio button
    $('input[name=type]:checked').change();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Whoops. I updated my answer to use the value 'Reset Password' instead of 'Password', so you can try that and let me know if it works. Also, do you have jquery setup for your project? If my updated code doesn't work, it might be useful for you to edit your question to include the markup that is created when you render the form.

Comment: Thanks for posting the html. It would be best if you edited your original post to include the html (excluding the javascript that I suggested) and then remove the answer that you posted below. I updated my answer again to account for your markup. Try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

HI Divey the generated html code is as follows -

```
<style type="text/css">label span.required { color: #B94A48; }span.help-inline, span.help-block { color: #888; font-size: .9em; font-style: italic; }</style><form action="employeetransaction.php" id="vertical" method="post" class="ewForm"><label for="vertical-element-0"></label><input type="hidden" name="form" value="vertical" id="vertical-element-0"/><label for="vertical-element-1"></label><input type="hidden" name="empno" value="1007" id="vertical-element-1"/><label for="vertical-element-2"></label><BR><label for="vertical-element-3"></label><BR><label for="vertical-element-4">
    Command Type to Employee : </label><label class="radio"> <input id="vertical-element-4-0" type="radio" name="type" value="Amount" checked="checked"/> 
    Loan Approval </label> <label class="radio"> <input id="vertical-element-4-1" type="radio" name="type" value="Reset Password"/> 
    Reset Password </label> <label for="vertical-element-5"></label><BR><label for="vertical-element-6"></label><BR><label for="vertical-element-7">
    Amount :</label><input type="text" name="amount" id="vertical-element-7"/><label for="vertical-element-8">Password 
    :</label><input type="text" name="password" id="vertical-element-8"/><div class="form-actions"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name class="btn btn-primary" id="vertical-element-9"/> <input type="button" value="Cancel" name onclick="history.go(-1);" class="btn" id="vertical-element-10"/></div></form><script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function() {      jQuery("#vertical").bind("submit", function() { 
            jQuery(this).find("input[type=submit]").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
        });jQuery("#vertical :input:visible:enabled:first").focus();}); </script><script>
$(function(){
    $('input[name=type]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Reset Password') {
            $('input[name=amount]').closest('.control-group').hide();
            $('input[name=password]').closest('.control-group').show();
        } else {
            $('input[name=amount]').closest('.control-group').show();
            $('input[name=password]').closest('.control-group').hide();
        }
    });

    // trigger the event for the selected radio button
    $('input[name=type]:checked').change();
});
</script>
```